# PayPal hosted checkout outside the US

Tags: paypal, payflowpro, payflowlink

Is it possible to implement Hosted Checkout Page Layout C outside the United States especially in Hungary?

I would like to implement divided checkout page into our website, where the customer has option to fill their card details without login/register to PayPal. Of course both case handled by PayPal behind of screen.

I'm looking for something like this: https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/paypal_payments_advanced.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nadj,

Unfortunately, Payments Advanced is only available to US merchants.

There are some Asian and European countries that can use the Hosted Solution Checkout process but it currently isn't available to Hungarian merchants - sorry!

I'll submit a feature request to allow Hungarian merchant access to it but I can't guarantee it will be implemented.

Comment: Can You suggest similar PayPal product supported card accept solution without PayPal sign in restrict and available in Hungary?

Comment: I don't believe there is an option for Hungarian merchants to accept credit card payments from buyers without requiring they have a PayPal account currently  - sorry.